# How to do incase sensitive search in firebase android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Do you know how to perform incase sensetive in firebase. 
Demonstration: Suppose database is have list of names such as [ John, jhonny, Jhonson, jackson].
If i enter key ‘j’ or ‘J’. i want all name from j to be show irrespective of cases of names.

Comment: I recommend making all names Uppercase before saving it to the database. This way you wouldn't have to search for 'j' or 'J'. You'd only look for 'J'.

Comment: This is just an alternative, I want an exact solution.

Comment: Similar to @RosárioPereiraFernandes but make a new secondary field which is the case-insensitive form of the original name so as to not lose that information.  So "name" and "caseInsensitiveName" and query on the "caseInsensitiveName" after first making the query case insensitive.